# How to add desktop shortcut on installation of UWP app?

Tags: uwp, desktop, shortcut

Upon installation, a shortcut does not get added to my Desktop, it gets added to start bar only. Is there any way I can add a shortcut to the desktop programmatically?

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?